# onAnimationEnd and accessing UI elements within it

Tags: android, android-animation

I have looked through the the documentation of `ValueAnimator` but didn't notice specific guideline on accessing UI elements in `onAnimatorEnd` method. However in the application I have in google play, I see many crashlytics reports originating in  `onAnimationEnd`. All of those crashes are mitigated by adding following code at the beginning of `onAnimationEnd`

`if(getActivity() != null && !getActivity.isFinishing() ) {
        ...
        }`

Does anyone know for sure if activity can be `destroyed` before animation ends? Also if activity is really destroyed why is `onAnimationEnd` getting called at all? I can certainly add above code to all my `onAnimationEnd` but want to make sure its not a incorrect solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know for sure if activity can be destroyed before animation ends?

Sure it can. Assume you have 10000ms long animation and you press back button. What will happen? Activity will be finished regardless animation has finished or no.

> Also if activity is really destroyed why is onAnimationEnd getting called at all?

It shouldn't. Instead, [`onAnimationCancel()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html#onAnimationCancel(android.animation.Animator)) will be called.

Comment: Are implying that onAnimationCancel() UI elements would still be there? For example if am doing viewGroup.setVisibility(GONE) in my onAnimationEnd would that viewGroup be present in onAnimationCancel?

Comment: @Subodh Nijsure, yes, it will.